# GET info from external Array/API/URL using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have the url http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=singleorderdata&marketid=132 which leads to an array.

I want to get the value of the first '`sellorders`' which in this case is: **0.00000048** and store it in the variable `$sellorderprice`.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Try using json_decode($output); it will convert a json string to an array format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just access the url contents thru `file_get_contents`. Your page actually return a JSON string, to get those values into meaningful data, decode it thru `json_decode`, after that access the data needed accordingly:

```
$url = 'http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=singleorderdata&marketid=132';
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
$sellorderprice = $data['return']['DOGE']['sellorders'][0]['price'];
echo $sellorderprice;
```

That code actually points directly to index zero `0` which gets the first price. If you need to get all items an just simply echo them all you need to iterate all items thru `foreach`:

```
foreach($data['return']['DOGE']['sellorders'] as $sellorders) {
    echo $sellorders['price'], '<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its simple, you just have to decode json like this:

```
    $json = file_get_contents("http://pubapi.cryptsy.com/api.php?method=singleorderdata&marketid=132");
    $arr = json_decode($json, true);
    $sellorderprice = $arr['return']['DOGE']['sellorders'][0]['price'];
```